# Howto build C# solution for different frameworks?

Tags: msbuild, build-process, nant

Which choices I have to build a VS2008 solution for different target frameworks, with only "one click"? I need to build for .net-2.0 and netcf-2.0.
The problem is that I need referencing different libraries for netcf-2.0.

I tried to do this with nant, but that seems to be a complicated task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use different build configurations.

When I did this I created a separate project for the CF version.  Inside the CF version the Compile property group uses links to all the original source files.

The CF and full-framework libraries are covered by independent projects. Each project can have an independent set of post-build or pre-build tasks, an independent set of references, a distinct set of #defined symbols, etc.

In my case, not all code used in the full-framework version of the library gets compiled for the CF version.  Using partial classes, I factor the code used only for the full-framework version into separate modules, and I don't add links for those source files into the CF project.

You could do the equivalent by using #if statements, and defining a CF symbol (or similar) in the .csproj file for the CF project.

Answer (score 0):

Keep different projects in a single solution with the same file list targeted to different framework versions.

Or group projects/solution by framework version.

Comment: That's how it is now. But I have also to do some post build tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating separate build configurations for each of the target frameworks?

For example, copy your Debug config and modify to your matching conditions and name it as FrameWork_2_0 and so on...

And now you can simply call an MSBuild/NAnt task on your solution once for each configuration